# load images using .map with reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Iam calling one of my images by get request but it does not show me the images in my .map, I have tried but I have not been able to and if I check my get request `"https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/anuncios_img/index1.php"` it brings all the images but it does not show me anything in my .map.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-pine-hgjsdp?file=/src/App.js:213-269

code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [ruta, setRuta1] = useState([]);

  const peticionGet_imagenes1 = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(`https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/anuncios_img/index1.php`)
      .then((res) => {
        setRuta1(res.data.ruta);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const imageNames = [ruta];

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      peticionGet_imagenes1();
    }, 1000);

    return () => setInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Galería de imágenes</h2>
      <div className="image-container">
        {imageNames.map((ruta, index) => (
          <img
            key={index}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            src={`https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/fotos_anuncios/Imagenes/${ruta}`}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: When you debug, what is the observed runtime value of `imageNames`?  How does it differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There where some erros in the code, it works like this:

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-cdn-yvdjmc?file=/src/App.js

First of all I removed this: `const imageNames = [ruta];` since it was creating an extra array of the response.

Then you can map `ruta` directly and obtain the item. You were doing this `(ruta, index)` and ruta here is not destructured to add it in the URL directly

See that the setInterval is removed just for demo purposes. If you needed you can added but i dont see to point neither

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [ruta, setRuta1] = useState([]);

  const peticionGet_imagenes1 = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(`https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/anuncios_img/index1.php`)
      .then((res) => {
        setRuta1(res.data); // here is res.data since you want to map it later
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    peticionGet_imagenes1();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Galería de imágenes</h2>
      <div className="image-container">
        {ruta?.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <img
              alt="test"
              key={index}
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
              src={`https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/fotos_anuncios/Imagenes/${item.ruta}`}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

if you want add `ruta directly in the src URL` you can do this, it is destructured:

```
{ruta?.map(({ ruta }, index) => {
          return (
            <img
              alt="test"
              key={index}
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
              src={`https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/fotos_anuncios/Imagenes/${ruta}`}
            />
          );
        })}
```

I hope it is more clear!